# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank' when calling fit on a Keras model with custom generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I want to build a Neural Network with two inputs: for image data and for numeric data. So I wrote custom data generator for that. The `train` and `validation` dataframes contain 11 columns:

1. `image_name` — path to the image;
2. 9 numeric features;
3. `target` — class for the item (last column).

The code for custom generator  (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60562073/1821692)):

```py
target_size = (224, 224)
batch_size = 1

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    train,
    x_col='image_name',
    y_col=train.columns[1:],
    target_size=target_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    shuffle=True,
    class_mode='raw')

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
    validation,
    x_col='image_name',
    y_col=validation.columns[1:],
    target_size=target_size,
    shuffle=False,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='raw')

def train_generator_func():
    count = 0
    while True:
        if count == len(train.index):
            train_generator.reset()
            break
        count += 1
        data = train_generator.next()
        
        imgs = []
        cols = []
        targets = []
        
        for k in range(batch_size):
            imgs.append(data[0][k])
            cols.append(data[1][k][:-1])
            targets.append(data[1][k][-1])
            
        yield [imgs, cols], targets
        
def validation_generator_func():
    count = 0
    while True:
        if count == len(validation.index):
            validation_generator.reset()
            break
        count += 1
        data = validation_generator.next()
                
        imgs = []
        cols = []
        targets = []
        
        for k in range(batch_size):
            imgs.append(data[0][k])
            cols.append(data[1][k][:-1])
            targets.append(data[1][k][-1])
            
        yield [imgs, cols], targets
```

Model building:

```py
def mlp_model(dim):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(8, input_dim=dim, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation="relu"))
    return model


def vgg16_model():
    model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=target_size+(3,))
    x=Flatten()(model.output)
    output=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(x) # because we have to predict the AUC
    model=Model(model.input,output)
    return model


def concatenated_model(cnn, mlp):
    combinedInput = concatenate([cnn.output, mlp.output])
    x = Dense(4, activation="relu")(combinedInput)
    x = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(x)    
    model = Model(inputs=[cnn.input, mlp.input], outputs=x)
    return model


def focal_loss(alpha=0.25,gamma=2.0):
    def focal_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred):
        bce = K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
        
        y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1.- K.epsilon())
        p_t = (y_true*y_pred) + ((1-y_true)*(1-y_pred))
        
        alpha_factor = 1
        modulating_factor = 1

        alpha_factor = y_true*alpha + ((1-alpha)*(1-y_true))
        modulating_factor = K.pow((1-p_t), gamma)

        # compute the final loss and return
        return K.mean(alpha_factor*modulating_factor*bce, axis=-1)
    return focal_crossentropy

cnn = vgg16_model()
mlp = mlp_model(9)

model = concatenated_model(cnn, mlp)

opt = Adam(lr=1e-5)
model.compile(loss=focal_loss(), metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC()],optimizer=opt)

nb_epochs = 2
nb_train_steps = train.shape[0]//batch_size
nb_val_steps = validation.shape[0]//batch_size

model.fit(
    train_generator_func(),
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_steps,
    epochs=nb_epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator_func(),
    validation_steps=nb_val_steps)
```

And fitting doesn't work with error message:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-253849fd34d6> in <module>
      9     epochs=nb_epochs,
     10     validation_data=validation_generator_func(),
---> 11     validation_steps=nb_val_steps)

d:\pyenv\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

d:\pyenv\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1061           use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1062           model=self,
-> 1063           steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
   1064 
   1065       # Container that configures and calls `tf.keras.Callback`s.

d:\pyenv\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weight, batch_size, steps_per_epoch, initial_epoch, epochs, shuffle, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, model, steps_per_execution)
   1108         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
   1109         distribution_strategy=ds_context.get_strategy(),
-> 1110         model=model)
   1111 
   1112     strategy = ds_context.get_strategy()

d:\pyenv\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in __init__(self, x, y, sample_weights, workers, use_multiprocessing, max_queue_size, model, **kwargs)
    796       return tensor_shape.TensorShape([None for _ in shape.as_list()])
    797 
--> 798     output_shapes = nest.map_structure(_get_dynamic_shape, peek)
    799     output_types = nest.map_structure(lambda t: t.dtype, peek)
    800 

d:\pyenv\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in map_structure(func, *structure, **kwargs)
    633 
    634   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 635       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    636       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    637 

d:\pyenv\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\nest.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    633 
    634   return pack_sequence_as(
--> 635       structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
    636       expand_composites=expand_composites)
    637 

d:\pyenv\keras-gpu\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py in _get_dynamic_shape(t)
    792       shape = t.shape
    793       # Unknown number of dimensions, `as_list` cannot be called.
--> 794       if shape.rank is None:
    795         return shape
    796       return tensor_shape.TensorShape([None for _ in shape.as_list()])

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'
```

So I tried to look at Keras sources but without any success.

If I use modified `train_generator` and `validation_generator` (`y_col='target'` instead of `y_col=train.columns[1:]`) everything works fine.

Comment: did you try class_mode = None, or class_mode = multi_output ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan Both doesn't work. `None` failed on `cols.append(data[1][k][:-1])` (index out of range). `multi_output` failed on building generator (`y` must be array). Another values (`binary`, `categorical`) doesn't work too.

Comment: what do u get while printing the values in your custom generator ?

Comment: @venkatakrishnan If I use `class_mode='raw'` `print(data)` prints 3 arrays: image, 9 element array and target. If I use `None` `print(data)` prints only image array. `multi_output`, `binary`, `categorical` fail before getting `data`.

Comment: keep it at raw. can you check the data type of first element inside 'col' inside your custom generator ? if its a tuple ? can u change it like cols.append(np.array(data[1][k][:-1]))

Comment: `type(data[1][k][:-1])` is `numpy.ndarray`. Nevertheless I changed `cols.append(data[1][k][:-1])` to `cols.append(np.array(data[1][k][:-1]))`. Didn't help.

Comment: Try converting the lists into numpy arrays, i.e. `yield [np.array(imgs), np.array(cols)], np.array(targets)`, and see if it helps.

Comment: @feeeper does the error persist ?

Comment: @today I tried it already without any success.

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Yes, I didn't solve it yet

Comment: @feeeper is it also possible to have a running example, maybe on colab notebook?

Comment: @feeeper Just to make sure: did you apply the fix I mentioned to `validation_generator_func` function as well? If so, do you still get the same error?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I'll try to create colab notebook later today

Comment: @today yes, New message: 2 root error(s) found. (0) Internal:  Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(8, 9), b.shape=(9, 9), m=8, n=9, k=9
[[node functional_3/dense_1/MatMul (defined at <ipython-input-45-253849fd34d6>:11) ]] [[assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/pivot_f/_3/_23]]
(1) Internal:  Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(8, 9), b.shape=(9, 9), m=8, n=9, k=9 [[node functional_3/dense_1/MatMul (defined at <ipython-input-45-253849fd34d6>:11) ]] 0 successful operations. 0 derived errors ignored. [Op:__inference_train_function_2784] Function call stack: train_function -> train_function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to convert all the individual objects returned by **both the training and validation generators** to Numpy arrays:

```
    yield [np.array(imgs), np.array(cols)], np.array(targets)
```

Alternatively, a simpler and much more efficient solution is to not iterate over the data batch at all; instead, we can take advantage of the fact that these objects are already Numpy arrays when returned by `ImageDataGenerator`, so we can write:

```
    imgs = data[0]
    cols = data[1][:,:-1]
    targets = data[1][:,-1:]
    yield [imgs, cols], targets
```

Comment: With these changes I have new message. Well formatted message on gist https://gist.github.com/feeeper/ffb70fd4b2e37f77f09a98f113898538

Comment: @feeeper Then the issue has hopefully resolved. The new error is an internal error related to BLAS. You may probably need to restart your GPU module or free it up. Please consult the related issues on Github such as [this one](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11812) for more information on how to resolve it.

Comment: Hmm... So I spent so many time with such stupid mistake? :D Thank a lot. I start run this notebook on google colab and everything working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

A different solution worked for me, just posting it here.
I ran into the problem working with two very similar dataframes in one notebook, where for one of them the error occurred.
I noticed the dtypes were slightly different int64 vs Int64, where the target column coded as Int64 gave the error.

For me the following worked:

```
dataframe[target_col] = dataframe[target_col].astype(int)
```